# How to change state during saga test

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, redux-saga

I have created polling saga which calls backend API until the response from the API is marked as done or until saga encounters an error.

```
export function* pollingSaga() {
  while (true) {
    try {
      yield call(/*call to BE API*/);
      const response = yield select(getResponse)
      if (response.result !== 'done') {
        yield call(delay, POLLING_INTERVAL_MS)
      } else {
        yield put(actions.cancel())
        return
      }
    } catch (error) {
      yield put(actions.cancel())
      return
    }
  }
}
```

I want to create test that checks if the delay is called properly and then if the response from API is `done` to check if the saga dispatches proper `cancel` action

```
it('should poll backend until maximum amount of rows is fetched', () => {
  const gen = pollingQueryResultsSaga()
  /*Here I would like to mock the call to the API so it returns response 'pending'*/
  gen.next() // call
  gen.next() // select 'pending' value
  expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(call(delay, 1000);
  /*Here I would like again mock API response but right now with 'done' value so my saga will return from `while` loop and dispatch cancel action */
  gen.next() // new iteration, call

  expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(put(actions.cancel());
  gen.next()
  expect(gen.next().done).toBe(true);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a value to the generator by calling `gen.next(value)` to change the `response` value. See [Generator.prototype.next()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next).

> The `value` will be assigned as a result of a `yield` expression

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
import { call, put, select } from 'redux-saga/effects';

const api = () => '';
const getResponse = (state) => state.response;
const POLLING_INTERVAL_MS = 1000;
export const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
export const actions = {
  cancel: () => ({ type: 'CANCEL' }),
};

export function* pollingSaga() {
  while (true) {
    try {
      yield call(api);
      const response = yield select(getResponse);
      console.log('response: ', response);
      if (response.result !== 'done') {
        yield call(delay, POLLING_INTERVAL_MS);
      } else {
        yield put(actions.cancel());
        return;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      yield put(actions.cancel());
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { actions, delay, pollingSaga } from '.';

describe('72260266', () => {
  it('should poll backend until maximum amount of rows is fetched', () => {
    const gen = pollingSaga();
    gen.next();
    gen.next();
    expect(gen.next({ result: 'pending' }).value).toEqual(call(delay, 1000));
    gen.next();
    gen.next();
    expect(gen.next({ result: 'done' }).value).toEqual(put(actions.cancel()));
    expect(gen.next().done).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS   redux-saga-examples  packages/redux-saga-examples/src/stackoverflow/72260266/index.test.ts (5.039 s)
  72260266
    ✓ should poll backend until maximum amount of rows is fetched (51 ms)

  console.log
    response:  { result: 'pending' }

      at packages/redux-saga-examples/src/stackoverflow/72260266/index.ts:16:15

  console.log
    response:  { result: 'done' }

      at packages/redux-saga-examples/src/stackoverflow/72260266/index.ts:16:15

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |      72 |       80 |   33.33 |   88.89 |                   
 index.ts |      72 |       80 |   33.33 |   88.89 | 24-25             
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.19 s
```